# functor of points for grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading section 16.7 of Vakil's Foundations of AG, which constructs the Grassmannian G(k,n) via its functor of points, namely B -> surjections O^n_B -> Q, where Q is locally free of rank k.

He then proceeds as follows: for I a k-element subset of [n], define the open subfunctor G(k,n)_I by those surjections O^n_B -> Q restricting to an injection on the coordinates corresponding to I. He then claims that G(k,n)_I is representable by A^k(n-k) (and that these patches glue by general nonsense). But to do this, he claims that if we have a surjection O^n -> Q that is injective when restricted to the first k coordinates, then this restriction is an isomorphism.

However, working over SpecZ, the surjection Z^2 -> Z sending (a,b) to 2a+3b does not induce an isomorphism when restricted to either factor.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: He's not claiming that this happens globally, is he? On $D(2)$ this restricts to an isomorphism on the first factor, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your confusion arises from the definition of $G(k,n)_I$ - it should be those surjections whose composition with $\mathcal{O}_B^I\to \mathcal{O}_B^n$ is an isomorphism. You might also expect that the surjection you gave needs to lie in the $\mathbb{Z}$-points of one of the $G(k,n)_I$. This is simply not the case. This is because a surjective morphism need not be surjective on points. However, there is a points criterion for surjectivity: $f:X\to Y$ is surjective if for every field $F$ and $y\in Y(F)$ there is an extension $E/F$ of fields and an $x\in X(E)$ such that $f(x) = y$ where $y$ is considered also as an element of $Y(E)$. You can check this criterion directly for the Grassmannian now, where for fields it is clear.